# define generic cast for all castable types

Tags: c#, generics, casting, type-conversion

I have the following generic class:

```
public class InclusionData<T>
{
    public T ThisObject { get; private set; }
    public T CopiedFromObject { get; private set; }
    public object OverwrittenOriginal { get; private set; }

    internal InclusionData(T thisObj, T copiedFromObj, object ovrwrtnOrgnl)
    {
        ThisObject = thisObj;
        CopiedFromObject = copiedFromObj;
        OverwrittenOriginal = ovrwrtnOrgnl;
    }
}
```

I want this class to be castable* into any `InclusionData<S>` for which `T` is castable to `S`. How do I do that?

(*Does not need to be an explicit/implicit cast, just some way of putting in an `InclusionData<T>` and getting out an `InclusionData<S>` with the same content.)

I tried to define a casting method inside `InclusionData` like this:

```
public InclusionData<S> Cast<S>() where T : S
{
    return new InclusionData<S>((S)ThisObject, (S)CopiedFromObject, OverwrittenOriginal);
}
```

but it gives compiler errors:

- the `T` in `where T : S` is marked red, saying `'InclusionData<T>.Cast<S>()' does not define type parameter 'T'`
- `(S)ThisObject` and the other two casts are marked red, saying `cannot convert type 'T' to 'S'`

So it seems that, although `T` is already a type parameter, I cannot define constraints on `S` using `T`. So how do I specify that `S` must be castable to `T`?

Comment: If you use an interface, you could make it covariant `IInclusionData<out T>`, and then  `IInclusionData<Cat>` is directly castable to `iInclusionData<Animal>`

Answer (score 0):

This one is not possible :

```
public InclusionData<S> Cast<S>() where T : S
```

Because T is the type that will have the constraint but T is not defined at the method level. It's defined at the class level.
For example, this is possible

```
public InclusionData<S> Cast<S>() where S : T
```

S (the type defined at the method level) will have the constraint to be a child of T (defined at the class level).

After than all other compilation errors disappeared but I don't know if it's what you're trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer said, `T : S` is not a possible generic constraint for the method, because it is constraining `T`, which is a generic parameter for the class, not the method. You can only constrain `S`.

I would make two static methods for this. This way the caller can specify the types that they want to convert between, and by doing this, they select the correct method:

```
// "casting" from superclass to subclass
public static InclusionData<S> Copy<S>(InclusionData<T> other) where S : T {
    return new InclusionData<S>((S)other.ThisObject, (S)other.CopiedFromObject, other.OverwrittenOriginal);
}

// "casting" from subclass to superclass
public static InclusionData<T> Copy<S>(InclusionData<S> other) where S : T {
    return new InclusionData<T>(other.ThisObject, other.CopiedFromObject, other.OverwrittenOriginal);
}
```

Example usage:

```
var d1 = new InclusionData<object>("Hello", "World", "Something");
// I can convert from object to string...
InclusionData<string> d2 = InclusionData<object>.Copy<string>(d1);
// and from string to object
d1 = InclusionData<object>.Copy<string>(d2);
```

Note that this doesn't handle the built in conversions between value types, like between `int` and `long`, or any user-defined conversion operators. Those you have to hardcode in yourself.